# How can I change the values ​of variables with the click of a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my index page displays all the projects from the database.

`@projects = Project.all`

But I also want to have some buttons that could change this list.I have methods for this. Like:

```
  def today
    @projects = Project.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
  end

  def this_week
    @projects = Project.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 1, DateTime.now.end_of_day + 6).all
  end
```

How can I add these methods to buttons and when I click change the display of the list of projects?

Comment: Where's your button code which shows what you have tried so far? This might help btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243200/how-to-call-a-controller-method-from-a-button-in-rails-4

Comment: here is my button: <%= button_to 'Call Action', home_today_path, method: :post, remote: true %>. I also added this to my routes post 'home/today'. BUT these actions do not change @projects

Comment: Where do these methods live? In the controller? In the model?

Comment: In the controller

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297623/custom-post-routes-for-create-action-not-fired-up

Answer (score 2):

A quick overview of MVC might help here.

- Model - the first level above the database, controls attributes of objects (e.g. Project has a date)
- Controller - the interaction between Models and Views (and routes, but set that aside)
- View - the interaction between the browser and the Controller

You want to have some "filtering" buttons on the index view.
Clicking this button will either:

1. Take the browser to a new URL
2. Trigger some javascript that will manage the context of the current view

Let me get you headed in the right direction for each of these options:

---

**Option 1A: New views for each button**

You could structure your controller something like this:

```rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def today
    @projects = Project.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
  end

  def this_week
    @projects = Project.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 1, DateTime.now.end_of_day + 6).all
  end
```

Then make routes that match:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...

  resources :projects do
    get 'today', on: :collection
    get 'this_week', on: :collection
  end

  ...
```

You'll also need to create views: `today.html.erb` and `this_week.html.erb`

Users will click a button and be taken to `projects/today` or `projects/this_week` views.

---

**OPTION 1B: allow your index to handle parameters filtering**

You could structure your controller something like this:

```rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    start_date = params[:start] || DateTime.now.beginning_of_day
    end_date = params[:end] || DateTime.now.end_of_day

    @projects = Project.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date, end_date).all
  end
```

then customize your buttons:

```
<%= button_to 'Today', projects_path() %>
<%= button_to 'This week', projects_path(start: DateTime.now.beginning_of_week, end: DateTime.now.end_of_week) %>
<%= button_to 'This year', projects_path(start: DateTime.now.beginning_of_year, end: DateTime.now.end_of_year) %>
```

This will re-load the `Projects#index` with parameters in the URL, like:

`"https://example.com/projects/?start=2019-01-01&end=2019-12-31"`

And you can access those parameters to intelligently filter your projects.

---

**Option 2: Javascript & AJAX**

This one is complicated. I recommend checking out some tutorials. Like this one:

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/

Comment: Excellent answer!